# mysql - can i make column refrence to table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

in mysql, there is some pre-created databases, in *information_schema* database contains a lot of stuff, among them :

> `information_schema.TABLES` contains `table_name`

which contains every table name in databases, and it's linked to table, when clicked it select the table for you

my question is, can i do the same thing to table?

i did (foreign key) or (indexes) for columns before but never tried for table, is it possible?

thanks!

Comment: "When clicked" implies this is a feature of your MySQL client, not MySQL itself.

Comment: @tadman if I'm right, you mean there is no way to do this in my table?

Comment: The table doesn't do this. MySQL doesn't do this. Only your client can do this, and if your client doesn't, then either get a different client or you'll just have to deal with it. There are *many* MySQL front-end tools to choose from, so try out a few and see which work best for you.

Comment: @tadman ok i got this, thank you! :)